# Isabelle multiply both sides of an equation (equational reasoning in Isar)

Tags: isabelle

I want to prove that inverse element is unique in a monoid `M`

```
theorem inverse_unique:
  assumes "u ⋅ v' = "
  assumes "v ⋅ u = "
  assumes "u ∈ M"
  assumes "v ∈ M"
  assumes "v' ∈ M"
  shows "v = v'"
proof -
  have "v ⋅ u ⋅ v' = v ⋅ "  
    apply (rule arg_cong[of "u ⋅ v'"  "λ x. v⋅x"])
```

The idea is to show the following steps

```
v⋅u⋅v'=⋅v' by congruence (multiplying both sides)
v⋅=⋅v' by monoid neutral element axiom
v⋅=v' by monoid neutral element axiom
v=v' done
```

Unfortunately I am stuck on the very first step. I don't want to use `auto` or any other automatic approach. I want to do it by hand to learn how to do it.
I've been trying with `apply (subst)` and `apply (rule arg_cong)` and many variations thereof. Nothing really works.

This is the definition of monoid that I am using

```
locale monoid =
  fixes M and composition (infixl "⋅" 70) and unit ("")
  assumes composition_closed [intro, simp]: "⟦ a ∈ M; b ∈ M ⟧ ⟹ a ⋅ b ∈ M"
    and unit_closed [intro, simp]: " ∈ M"
    and associative [intro]: "⟦ a ∈ M; b ∈ M; c ∈ M ⟧ ⟹ (a ⋅ b) ⋅ c = a ⋅ (b ⋅ c)"
    and left_unit [intro, simp]: "a ∈ M ⟹  ⋅ a = a"
    and right_unit [intro, simp]: "a ∈ M ⟹ a ⋅  = a"
```

and the theorem is in `context monoid begin`

Other thing I've tried is this

```
theorem inverse_unique:
  assumes uv1:"u ⋅ v' = "
  assumes vu1:"v ⋅ u = "
  assumes um:"u ∈ M"
  assumes vm:"v ∈ M"
  assumes v'm:"v' ∈ M"
  shows "v = v'"
proof -
  from uv1 have "v ⋅ u ⋅ v' = v ⋅ "
    apply(rule subst)
    apply(rule associative)
```

which gets me quite far but the associative rule requires now

```
 1. v ∈ M
 2. u ∈ M
 3. v' ∈ M
```

However, if I add those to `from`

```
from uv1 um vm v'm have "v ⋅ u ⋅ v' = v ⋅ "
```

then `apply(rule subst)` yields `Failed to apply proof method⌂`.

Another thing I've tried is this

```
theorem inverse_unique:
  assumes uv1:"u ⋅ v' = "
  assumes vu1:"v ⋅ u = "
  assumes um:"u ∈ M"
  assumes vm:"v ∈ M"
  assumes v'm:"v' ∈ M"
  shows "v = v'"
proof -
  from uv1 have "v ⋅ (u ⋅ v') = v ⋅ "
    apply (rule subst) 
    apply (rule refl)
    done
  from this um vm v'm have "v ⋅ u ⋅ v' = v ⋅ "
    apply (subst associative)  
    apply (assumption)
    apply (assumption)
    apply (assumption)
    apply (assumption)
    done
  from this vu1 have " ⋅ v' = v ⋅ "
```

which actually works, but then again I get stuck at the last `from this vu1 have " ⋅ v' = v ⋅ "` because I still don't know how to substitute  for `vu1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If substitution rules require assumptions, it's often convenient to supply these through the `[OF ...]` modifier behind the equality fact. Also, rewriting in Isar proofs usually makes more fun using the `unfolding` keyword. Your proof from https://stackoverflow.com/a/75362601/5158425 would then read:

```
theorem inverse_unique:
  assumes uv1: "u ⋅ v' = "
  assumes vu1: "v ⋅ u = "
  assumes um: "u ∈ M"
  assumes vm: "v ∈ M"
  assumes v'm: "v' ∈ M"
  shows "v = v'"
proof -
  have "v ⋅ (u ⋅ v') = v ⋅ " unfolding uv1 by (rule refl)
  from this have "v ⋅ u ⋅ v' = v ⋅ " unfolding associative[OF vm um v'm] by assumption
  from this have " ⋅ v' = v ⋅ " unfolding vu1 by assumption
  from this have "v' = v ⋅ " unfolding left_unit[OF v'm] by assumption
  from this show "v = v'" unfolding right_unit[OF vm] by (rule sym)
qed
```

We can make this even simpler by use of the `also have ...` keywords to chain equalities:

```
proof -
  have ‹v = v ⋅ › using right_unit[OF vm, symmetric] .
  also have ‹... = v ⋅ (u ⋅ v')› unfolding uv1 ..
  also have ‹... = v ⋅ u ⋅ v'› using associative[OF vm um v'm, symmetric] .
  also have ‹... =  ⋅ v'› unfolding vu1 ..
  finally show ?thesis unfolding left_unit[OF v'm] .
qed
```

Here, the `...` on the left-hand sides abbreviate the right-hand sides of the preceding lines. Moreover, the proof is elementar to a level that we can use the proof methods for immediate proof `.` and default proof `..`. They do roughly the same ”by assumption” and “by rule” would.

Answer (score 0):

I found a full proof

```
theorem inverse_unique:
  assumes uv1:"u ⋅ v' = "
  assumes vu1:"v ⋅ u = "
  assumes um:"u ∈ M"
  assumes vm:"v ∈ M"
  assumes v'm:"v' ∈ M"
  shows "v = v'"
proof -
  from uv1 have "v ⋅ (u ⋅ v') = v ⋅ "
    apply (rule subst) 
    apply (rule refl)
    done
  from this um vm v'm have "v ⋅ u ⋅ v' = v ⋅ "
    apply (subst associative)  
    apply (assumption)
    apply (assumption)
    apply (assumption)
    apply (assumption)
    done
  from this vu1 have " ⋅ v' = v ⋅ "
    apply(subst vu1[symmetric])
    apply(assumption)
    done
  from v'm this have "v' = v ⋅ "
    apply(subst left_unit[symmetric])
    apply(assumption)
    apply(assumption)
    done
  from vm this show "v = v'"
    apply(subst right_unit[symmetric])
    apply(assumption)
    apply(rule sym)
    apply(assumption)
    done
qed
```

but it is quite long and ugly. I feel like this could have been done better (without resorting to `auto`).

Comment: I think the have/also would help here: `have "a=b" sorry also have "...=c" sorry also have "...=d" sorry finally have "a=d" .`

Comment: There are a lot of ways of shortening, for instance, combining `unfolding` and `[OF ...]`:
```
have "v ⋅ (u ⋅ v') = v ⋅ " unfolding uv1 by (rule refl)
from this have "v ⋅ u ⋅ v' = v ⋅ " unfolding associative[OF vm um v'm] by assumption
from this have " ⋅ v' = v ⋅ " unfolding vu1 by assumption
from this have "v' = v ⋅ " unfolding left_unit[OF v'm] by assumption
from this show "v = v'" unfolding right_unit[OF vm] by (rule sym)
```